# How to load a view in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have sliced the html of my website in multiple files as per the demand of the site structure and saved them all as views in views folder of codeigniter.

I am loading the same from a common controller as:

```
$this->load->view($this->config->item('templates_path') . 'header', $this->data);
$this->load->view($this->config->item('templates_path') . 'navbar', $this->data);
$this->load->view($this->config->item('templates_path') . 'main-container', $this->data);
$this->load->view($this->config->item('templates_path') . $sidebar, $this->data);
$this->load->view($this->config->item('templates_path') . 'main-content', $this->data);
$this->load->view($this->config->item('templates_path') . 'breadcrumb', $this->data);
$this->load->view($this->config->item('templates_path') . 'page-content', $this->data);
$this->load->view($this->config->item('templates_path') . 'main-content-end', $this->data);
$this->load->view($this->config->item('templates_path') . 'footer');
$this->load->view($this->config->item('templates_path') . 'main-container-end', $this->data); 
$this->load->view($this->config->item('templates_path') . 'bottom');
```

Some view files from the above have only few HTML Tags in the file like:
View File

```
$this->load->view($this->config->item('templates_path') . 'main-content-end', $this->data);
```

has only

```
</div><!-- /.main-container -->
```

is there a way in codeigniter to load the html part directly without creating it as a new view file?

Comment: You can include this file in other view files with a simple php `include();` statement.

Comment: Why can't you combine all those parts into one or two files?  In my CodeIgniter project, I have a template controller that inserts my content into a single template file.  I guess I just can't see why you'd need to do all that.

Comment: use layout library and combine all elements in layout view see tutorial layout library : https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/layout-library

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in your Views directory and call it something like 'includes' or whatever you want. 
Then you can include these HTML template pieces in other views using the following PHP:

```
include('/path/to/include/file-to-include.php');
```

*Comments:

• the path to the file should be relative to the view file

• the included file doesn't have to be a .php file, it can be an HTML file if you like (or it can include PHP code if you want it to)

• i tested this in my local installation of codeigniter and it worked as expected*

Comment: The OP said he did not want to create a View file for a very small amount of HTML.  How is using a PHP `include` much different?  For a single HTML tag, maybe a PHP `echo` is more appropriate.  Or maybe the OP needs to create a Controller to insert his content into a single template.

Comment: I didn't suggest creating a view file but what other option of getting it into the rendered page does the OP have than an include()... I am suggesting that these small snippet elements just get put in an includes folder and added to the relevant views (some view will be returned to the browser, this solution tries to reduce the amount of subview pieces used to make up the final rendered view

Comment: I guess I just don't see a large difference between your answer and what he's already doing (using the same number of external files).  Why can't he just combine all those external pieces into a one template?

Comment: I guess it depends how much of his overall site is templateable vs. custom from view to view... in my case, my pages vary pretty custom so the only areas I treat as truly templated and constant are my header, nav and footer. I didn't need to separate my items out further but I do have it structured with 2 template files (header/nav and footer) being included in my view files -- the goal of my answer was to reduce the view load calls because the static elements would be included in the individual view files (sort of a set-it-and-forget it scenario because it is being added automatically.

Comment: I don't particularly have a problem with your answer... I just don't understand what the OP is talking about here,  _"I have sliced the html of my website in multiple files as per the demand of the site structure"_, but then implies everything goes through a "common controller".  Either everything is common or it isn't.  If it's common, then why slice it up into such tiny pieces in the first place, only to complain that the pieces are too small?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, creating a view 'file' is required, an html or a php file must be created and included, the `load->view` part just does it for you, it's exactly like include, only it throws in some CI logic.

What I normally do for my websites is create a function my MY_Controller called 'mainTemplate', (name can vary)

```
function mainTemplate($views = null, $data)
{
$this->load->view('header',$data);
$this->load->view('breadcrumbs',$data);

//now some logic, if we have a string for a view, we just load the string
if(is_string($views)
$this->load->view($views,$data)

//if it's an array of views, we just iterate over the array and show each view
foreach ($views as $view)
{
    $this->load->view($view,$data);
}  
 //and now the footer
  $this->load->view('footer',$data);  
}
```

now you can call inside your controllers something like this :

```
$this->mainTemplate('pageContent',$data);
```

You can create a new function for each template and include the views you need for each template. So I have for example a login template, a  main page template, a product template etc.

hope it's closer to what you asked.

Comment: I am already doing same my question is about loading some HTML tags without creating view files. Thanks

Comment: There's no way to display HTML code without actually writing that HTML  somewhere.. You could do it through the PHP itself which is horrible, something like ` echo "<a href='/home'>home page</a>" ` , However that's really bad practice, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Create a view file and store it in the views folder if the codeigniter.
syntax to load view files

```
$this->load->view('filenane');
```

file name not require to have extension.
for more detail please prefer [codeigniter](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

make complete design in ur view side then use the following code to load ur view

```
$this->load->view('filenane');
```

dont use extention in filename to load ur view just use ur file name.